# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wait until page has been fully loaded

Tags: c#, web-scraping, dynamics-crm, webbrowser-control

I have been trying a lot of different solutions with `wait` and `async`. Nothing seems to work. I was not able to find solution that actually fully waits until page has been fully loaded. All codes are waiting some time but not until page has been loaded and I am getting an error on next process.

How I can set for example code into wait mode until `Document.GetElementById("quickFind_text_0")` element has been found on page?

Here is my code:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://company.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx?app=d365default&pagetype=entitylist&etn=opportunity");

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_text_0").SetAttribute("value", "Airbus");

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_text_0").InnerText = "Airbus";

        //Thread.Sleep(2000);

        HtmlElement fbLink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("mainContent").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_button_0"); ;
        fbLink.InvokeMember("click");
    }
```

P.S. I have to do this "twice" otherwise it is not working:

```
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_text_0").SetAttribute("value", "Airbus");

    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_text_0").InnerText = "Airbus";
```

In VBA this works:

```
    While .Busy
        DoEvents

    Wend
    While .ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
```

Is it possible to do the same in C#?

---

**EDIT:**

My full code below. For some reason async/await does not work.

> System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Message=Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.   Source=v.0.0.01
> StackTrace:    at v._0._0._01.Browser.<button7_Click>d__7.MoveNext()
> in C:\Users\PC\source\repos\v.0.0.01\v.0.0.01\Browser.cs:line 69

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace v.0._0._01
{

    public static class WebBrowserExtensions
    {
        public static Task<Uri> DocumentCompletedAsync(this WebBrowser wb)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Uri>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
            handler = (_, e) =>
            {
                wb.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
                tcs.TrySetResult(e.Url);
            };
            wb.DocumentCompleted += handler;
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }

    public partial class Browser : Form
    {

        public Browser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://company.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx?app=d365default&pagetype=entitylist&etn=opportunity");
            await webBrowser1.DocumentCompletedAsync(); // async magic
            HtmlElement fbLink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("shell-container").Document.GetElementById("mainContent").Document.GetElementById("quickFind_button_0"); ;
            fbLink.InvokeMember("click");

        }

    }

}
```

Also now I have noticed that `quickFind_text_0` and `quickFind_button_0` always starts with same words but numbers are changing like `quickFind_text_1` and `quickFind_button_1` or `quickFind_text_2` and `quickFind_button_2`. However by manual clicking everything works with `quickFind_text_0` and `quickFind_button_0`.

Comment: Is this a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`? It will raise a [`DocumentCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)event when the page is loaded; put your scraping code in that.

Comment: @DourHighArch yes. It is `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`. I will try that

Comment: This will wait until page is loaded, how I can add more waits? For example I need to perform text input to textbox and wait after that, where I have `//Thread.Sleep(2000);` currently. After that click button. I think I need to wait until certain element has been found on page and if it has been not found for 30 seconds, end process.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with chaining repeatedly the `.Document.GetElementById(...)`. Somehow it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an extension method for easy awaiting of the `DocumentCompleted` event:

```
public static class WebBrowserExtensions
{
    public static Task<Uri> DocumentCompletedAsync(this WebBrowser wb)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Uri>();
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (_, e) =>
        {
            wb.DocumentCompleted -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(e.Url);
        };
        wb.DocumentCompleted += handler;
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://company.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx");
    await webBrowser1.DocumentCompletedAsync(); // async magic
    HtmlElement fbLink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("quickFind_button_0");
    fbLink.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

The lines after the `await` will run after the page has completed loading.

---

**Update:** Here is another extension method for awaiting a specific element to appear in the page:

```
public static async Task<HtmlElement> WaitForElementAsync(this WebBrowser wb,
    string elementId, int timeout = 30000, int interval = 500)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var element = wb.Document.GetElementById(elementId);
            if (element != null) return element;
        }
        catch { }
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeout) throw new TimeoutException();
        await Task.Delay(interval);
    }
}
```

It can be used for example after invoking a click event that modifies the page using XMLHttpRequest:

```
someButton.InvokeMember("click");
var mainContentElement = await webBrowser1.WaitForElementAsync("mainContent", 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I don't know where is the problem, but I think this does not wait as I am getting an error on the next command. If I run all my commands separately but different buttons, waiting for processes to finish myself, then everything works fine.

Comment: Does the page contain `frame`s or `iframe`s? This would explain why the page is not fully loaded on the first `DocumentCompleted` event.

Comment: I included in my answer another extension method that you may find useful (`WaitForElementAsync`).